# How to call a method in another namespace

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces

Is it possible to call a method in another namespace in PHP? If so, how?

I'm trying to write a WordPress plugin. For adherence to best practices, I'm encapsulating my code in its own namespace to prevent conflicts. However, when I try to call the `wp_get_current_user()` function, I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sln\wp_get_current_user()
```

An excerpt from my code:

```
<?php

Namespace sln;

class SimpleLoginNotifications {


    function __construct() {

        $user_data = wp_get_current_user();

        add_action('wp_login', 'sln_send_login_notification');

    }


[...]


?>
```

Comment: you have to start at the root with \ and then the namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare the namespace `sln` in your file, all functions/methods/constants/classes are assumed under that namespace. So if `wp_get_current_user()` is not declared in the `sln` namespace you need to call it using its fully qualified name or [import via `use`](http://php.net/language.namespaces.importing) at the top of your script. If it's in the global namespace then you need qualify it with a leading backslash `\wp_get_current_user()`.